# MVC3 - Override Attribute On Base Class Declaration

Tags: oop, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

We have a base controller which all of our other controllers inherit and a custom RequireHttps attribute.  This custom attribute has a switch to either force SSL or to rely on a setting in a config file.  The base controller is decorated with this attribute and set to rely on the config setting, which is the correct behavior for 95% of our controllers.  We have a couple controllers, however, that we want to set to always require SSL.  If I apply the attribute to those couple controllers to force SSL then the RequireHttpsAttribute code is run twice (probably not a huge problem, but certainly not ideal).

Is there any way for me to override the attribute declaration on the base class with the attribute declaration on the child?  I suspect I cannot, but would like to know for sure.

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

How about creating another custom attribute which will inject into the current HttpContext some value indicating that SSL is required. Then you will decorate the controllers that need to be an exception with this attribute. Then modify your custom RequireHttps attribute yo look for the presence of this value in the HttpContext and enforce SSL.

You only need to ensure that this new filter will run before the custom RequireHttps attribute. This could be done either using the `Order` property.